# Spring Boot query from controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `User` class like this :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
@Id @GeneratedValue Long userID;
String eMail;
String passwordHash;
}
```

And I have data like this :

```
[{"userID":1,"passwordHash":"asdasd","email":"admin@admin.com"},
{"userID":2,"passwordHash":"12345","email":"admin1asdasd@admin.com"}]
```

I have two method in my *controller class*, one - to get single user :

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
User one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
}
```

Other method to retrieve all user :

```
@GetMapping("/user")
List<User> all() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

In my browser, going to this address - `http://localhost:8080/user` , I can see these data. And if I goto `http://localhost:8080/user/id` I can get a specific value.

Now my question is how can access data like `http://localhost:8080/user/email/passwordHash`? I am quite sure that it is not possible, because I haven't stored data in that way.

As my main target is to verify login, I have already written a `@Query` in my repository interface. Here it is :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Query("select u from User u where u.eMail = ?1 and u.passwordHash = ?2")
List<User> listByLoginCredential(String emailAddress,String passwordHash);
 }
```

**Can Anyone tell me how can I do this,use this method of this interface?**

Comment: I think for security concern you should not use GET method when you want to send password data although you have to encrypt password. Just use POST method instead.

Comment: @PanupongKongarn can you please describe a little ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can can achieve what you want by adding the following method to the controller class:

```
@GetMapping("/user/{emailAddress}/{passwordHash}")
List<User> byMailAndPassword(@PathVariable String emailAddress, @PathVariable String passwordHash) {
    return repository.listByLoginCredential(emailAddress, passwordHash)
}
```

On the other hand you say that your main goal is to verify login, so it looks like you are doing authentication. If you have time you should look into doing it with spring security https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#initial

Comment: This doesn't work. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkEIg.png).

Comment: oops, I made a mistake in the first line, it should be like this
@GetMapping("/user/{emailAddress}/{passwordHash}")
fixed in the answer

Comment: Now this thing is working correctly.  But one more thing, that *securing-web* tutorial you have given me, seems little different to me. Can you tell me how can I integrate that with *react.js*?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with react.js and can't help you with it's side.
The main thing I wanted to point out is that you should not reinvent the wheel but use one of the common approaches to authentication like "basic authentication" and "token based authentication".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.
Or you can also create procedure in Database and call stored procedure with Spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Login is related to security so ideally you should create a separate post method and use the repository method. Always make sure to follow the best practice.

Spring security is something you can utilize for better authentication and authorization.